# JTable inside a JScrollPane with a fixed width

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, layout-manager

I have a JTable with a few columns and potentially very many rows. I only want to display 3 rows at a time, and I want the width of the JTable to be 400, **including the width of the scroll bar**.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
public class SwingDrivesMeMad
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Object[][] rowData = { {"Homer", "beer"},
                               {"Marge", "wine"},
                               {"Bart", "coke"},
                               {"Lisa", "water"},
                               {"Maggie", "milk"} };
        Object[] headerData = { "name", "beverage" };

        JTable table = new JTable(rowData, headerData)
        {
            public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()
            {
                return new Dimension(400, getRowHeight() * 3);
            }
        };

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("learn you a barkeep for great good!");
        frame.add(scrollPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

The height is perfect. Unfortunately, the width is 400 **plus** the width of the scrollbar, with a total of 415. This messes up the layout, because there is a graphics area with a fixed width of 400 directly above the table, and both components should line up perfectly. Having the table be slightly bigger just looks bad.

Of course I could simply set the width to 385, because on my system, scrollbars appear to take 15 pixels, but that does not seem very portable. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Did you try to set the size of the `JScrollPane` instead of the `JPanel`s one?

Comment: How's setting it to a hardwired 385 pixels less portable than setting it to 400?

Comment: @msrd0 That works perfectly for the width, but not for the height, because the header is not taken into account. How do I get the height of the header? `scrollPane.getColumnHeader().getHeight()` causes a `NullPointerException`. Also, I'm not a Swing expert, but I have read countless times that `setXXXSize` is evil.

Comment: @HenriqueOrdine Because the graphics area above it is exactly 400 pixels, on all systems. I know it, because I programmed it that way :) But the width of the scrollbar just *happens* to be 15 on my system.

Comment: You don't need `setXxxSize()` - create a new Container (`JPanel`), overwrite `getPreferredSize()` of it, and give it a LayoutManager that automatically sets the size of the children to its parent (like `CardLayout`, or `BorderLayout`). Instead of overwriting `getPreferredSize` you could also use a `LayoutManager` in the Container's subcomponent that sets its size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, none of the proposed solutions were pixel-perfect. So I came up with a hack:

How about trying a width of 400 first, then calculate the actual width, and finally correct for the excess?

```
JTable table = new JTable(rowData, headerData)
{
    private static final int DESIRED_WIDTH = 400;

    Dimension dim = new Dimension(DESIRED_WIDTH, Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    {
        JScrollPane dummy = new JScrollPane(this);
        dummy.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(dummy);
        frame.pack();
        int actualWidth = dummy.getSize().width;
        frame.dispose();
        int excess = actualWidth - DESIRED_WIDTH;
        dim = new Dimension(DESIRED_WIDTH - excess, getRowHeight() * 3);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()
    {
        return dim;
    }
};
```

Now `scrollPane.getSize().width` is exactly 400. Yes, it's a hack. But hey, it works!

Comment: I'd create a new class for that instead of making an Anonymus Inner Type

Comment: @msrd0 Agreed, this was just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Of course, and everybody who is no Java beginner would understand, but I would edit it to make it more useable to Java Beginners

Comment: @msrd0 Maybe this is just me, but I don't think Java beginners should touch Swing at all unless they want to lose their sanity ;)

Comment: Well, everybody writes his first Swing app at some time, and I didn't deal with Anonymus Inner Classes until I extended `MouseAdapter`

Comment: *"Maybe this is just me, but I don't think Java beginners should touch Swing at all unless they want to lose their sanity ;)"* It scares me when people doing GUI programming (Swing or any other toolkit) do not understand basic looping structures, control statements, or how to read a stack trace/error report.. (not implying that's the case here).

Comment: -1Mio, simple wrong, user with `90k+` should be more ..., and wise..., I'm leaving any *FlameWars*, have look at `getPreferredScrollableViewportSize` with `Flow/GridBag/SpringLayout`

Comment: @mKorbel What do you mean "have look at getPreferredScrollableViewportSize"? That's exactly what I'm using in my answer!